# Using Linq order by an object's property Vb.Net

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have a datatable of pointshape Objects in a map and I want to order this list by Object.baseshape.label.y which is a double value. How can I do this using Linq? 
I Have implemented this code so far

```
Dim query As IEnumerable(Of DataRow) = From result In dataArray.AsEnumerable() Order By result.Field(Of Object)("MapShapes") Descending
```

but I want something like this

```
Dim query As IEnumerable(Of DataRow) = From result In dataArray.AsEnumerable() Order By result.Field(Of Object)("MapShapes")..baseshape.label.y Descending
```

Comment: Instead of Field(Of Object), can you use Field(Of WhateverConcreteTypeItReallyIs)?

Comment: Yes I can and this is the answer . The Type is MapSuite.BaseMapShape

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the specific object type in the Field(Of ...) like this...

```
Dim query = From result In dataArray.AsEnumerable() Order By result.Field(Of MapSuite.BaseMapShape)("MapShapes").label.y Descending
```